# React Native Create one application which will call one API Using thread and store it in some file

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native Would like to get any good solution for following task:
Create one application which will call one API
(https://api.napster.com/v2.0/playlists?apikey=ZTk2YjY4MjMtMDAzYy00MTg4LWE2MjYtZDIzNjJmMmM0YTdm).
Using thread and store it in some file.

Current Code

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    return fetch('https://api.napster.com/v2.0/playlists?apikey=ZTk2YjY4MjMtMDAzYy00MTg4LWE2MjYtZDIzNjJmMmM0YTdm')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJSON) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJSON.playlists,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })

  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      )
    } else {

      let dbSource = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
        return (
          <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
            <Text>{val.name}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      })

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {dbSource}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: do you want to store file in local DB or just in a single file?

Comment: yes in local DB

Comment: I able to call API using fetch and as of now I'm displaying data on View. but not familier with how to handle it with thread to store in some file